# Running HMA on VPS but still being able to connect via Remote Desktop

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, ddns

Right, here's the tricky situation

We have a VPS ( windows 2008 )
We have a bot installed on this which needs to run behind HMA ( hide my ass VPN )

The obvious issue- 
- IF we are connected to the VPS using remote desktop to control the bot, the second HMA VPN is initiated, we get kicked out of remote desktop ..

What we were told was getting around this would be to use a service like No-ip DDNS .. and connect to the server using the DDNS ... but even with this , the second HMA runs, the remote desktop collapses..

is there any suggestion on what we could be doing wrong and if what we want is going to be technically possible?

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood what DDNS does. DDNS allows the server to update it's DNS name *after* HMA is connected so you can later *reconnect* to it's new IP.

The issue you're having shows a lack of understanding of basic networking. When you connect to the VPN, your default route changes to the VPN so that your server sends all internet traffic over the VPN. Meanwhile you're still trying to send RDP traffic to the non-VPN address and the server doesn't know what to do with it.

The "easy" solution is to do nothing. Once HMA connects, your DDNS client will update your DNS record (if you have it set up correctly) and after a few minutes/hours you should be able to connect to the new IP using said DNS.

The "proper" solution is to set up multihoming or a static route bypassing the VPN to the IP address you are connecting to the server *from*, i.e. your home broadband IP address. This isn't easy but here's a starting point:

https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/10026/how-to-bypass-vpn-for-specific-websites/

(In your case, what you want to do is pretend your home connection is the 'website' you want to bypass the VPN for)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however perhaps my question was phrased the wrong way.. however we have since managed to fix this and now have the solution in place using No-ip , HMA And VPS .. working as we hoped for.